# How to get each element out of a list or paired elements for seaborn heatmap python?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with paired elements with corresponding values, I would like to get each element out separately to use it for a heatmap.
I have this:

```
0 1
0 (a, b) 345
1 (a, c) 345
2 (a, d) 345
3 (a, e) 345
4 (a, f) 345
5 (b, c) 345
6 (b, d) 345
7 (b, e) 345
8 (b, f) 345
9 (c, d) 345
10 (c, e) 345
11 (c, f) 345
12 (d, e) 345
13 (d, f) 345
14 (e, f) 345
```

I would like to get this:

```
0   a   b   c   d   e   f
a   1   345 345 345 345 345
b   345 1   345 345 345 345
c   345 345 1   345 345 345
d   345 345 345 1   345 345
e   345 345 345 345 1   345
f   345 345 345 345 345 1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
I already tried this: [how to convert pair lists (to matrix) to heat map; python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115909/how-to-convert-pair-lists-to-matrix-to-heat-map-python) but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
df[['2','3']]=pd.DataFrame(df['0'].values.tolist())
df.pivot_table(index='2',columns='3',values='1',fill_value=1)
```